# sklearn - Cross validation with multiple scores

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I would like to compute the **recall**, **precision** and **f-measure** of a cross validation test for different classifiers.
*scikit-learn* comes with [cross_val_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html) but unfortunately such method does not return multiple values.

I could compute such measures by calling **three times** *cross_val_score* but that is not efficient. Is there any better solution?

By now I wrote this function:

```
from sklearn import metrics

def mean_scores(X, y, clf, skf):

    cm = np.zeros(len(np.unique(y)) ** 2)
    for i, (train, test) in enumerate(skf):
        clf.fit(X[train], y[train])
        y_pred = clf.predict(X[test])
        cm += metrics.confusion_matrix(y[test], y_pred).flatten()

    return compute_measures(*cm / skf.n_folds)

def compute_measures(tp, fp, fn, tn):
     """Computes effectiveness measures given a confusion matrix."""
     specificity = tn / (tn + fp)
     sensitivity = tp / (tp + fn)
     fmeasure = 2 * (specificity * sensitivity) / (specificity + sensitivity)
     return sensitivity, specificity, fmeasure
```

It basically sums up the confusion matrix values and once you have *false positive*, *false negative* etc you can easily compute the recall, precision etc... But still I don't like this solution :)

Comment: What's wrong with using `classification_report`? See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html#sklearn.metrics.classification_report

Comment: You have basically taken the essence of `cross_val_score` and adapted it to your case. This seems like a perfectly viable option, I don't see how to do it better. Please see my answer on an explanation of the problem and a workaround, in case you feel like modifying sklearn code.

Comment: @EdChum this doesn't do any cross validation. You measure the performance of the model based on a single pre-training phase.

Comment: Calling `cross_val_score` 3 times won't be very good idea. You have to be careful to use the same test/train sets.

Comment: @Dror yes you're right, I misread the question at the time

Comment: [scikit-learn now handles multiple metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45060368/6156647) in `GridSearchCV`, `RandomizedSearchCV` and `cross_validate` (see [the doc](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/model_evaluation.html#multimetric-scoring))

Answer (score 19):

Now in scikit-learn: `cross_validate` is a new function that can evaluate a model on multiple metrics.
This feature is also available in `GridSearchCV` and `RandomizedSearchCV` ([doc](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/model_evaluation.html#multimetric-scoring)).
It has been [merged recently in master](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/7388)  and will be available in v0.19.

From the [scikit-learn doc](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/cross_validation.html#the-cross-validate-function-and-multiple-metric-evaluation):

> The `cross_validate` function differs from `cross_val_score` in two ways: 1. It allows specifying multiple metrics for evaluation. 2.
>   It returns a dict containing training scores, fit-times and score-times in addition to the test score.

The typical use case goes by:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
iris = load_iris()
scoring = ['precision', 'recall', 'f1']
clf = SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, random_state=0)
scores = cross_validate(clf, iris.data, iris.target == 1, cv=5,
                        scoring=scoring, return_train_score=False)
```

See also [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_multi_metric_evaluation.html).

Answer (score 7):

The solution you present represents exactly the functionality of `cross_val_score`, perfectly adapted to your situation. It seems like the right way to go.

`cross_val_score` takes the argument `n_jobs=`, making the evaluation parallelizeable. If this is something you need, you should look into replacing your for loop with a parallel loop, using `sklearn.externals.joblib.Parallel`.

On a more general note, a discussion is going on about the problem of multiple scores in the issue tracker of scikit learn. A representative thread can be found [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1850). So while it looks like future versions of scikit-learn will permit multiple outputs of scorers, as of now, this is impossible.

A **hacky** (disclaimer!) way to get around this is to change the code in `cross_validation.py` ever so slightly, by removing a condition check on whether your score is a number. However, this suggestion is very version dependent, so I will present it for version `0.14`.

1) In IPython, type `from sklearn import cross_validation`, followed by `cross_validation??`. Note the filename that is displayed and open it in an editor (you may need root priviliges).

2) You will find [this code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.14.X/sklearn/cross_validation.py#L1066), where I have already tagged the relevant line (1066). It says

```
    if not isinstance(score, numbers.Number):
        raise ValueError("scoring must return a number, got %s (%s)"
                         " instead." % (str(score), type(score)))
```

These lines need to be removed. In order to keep track of what was there once (if ever you want to change back), replace it with the following

```
    if not isinstance(score, numbers.Number):
        pass
        # raise ValueError("scoring must return a number, got %s (%s)"
        #                 " instead." % (str(score), type(score)))
```

If what your scorer returns doesn't make `cross_val_score` choke elsewhere, this should resolve your issue. Please let me know if this is the case.

Comment: In case this sounds scary: I have been working with this patched version of scikit learn since the introduction of this `numbers.Number` condition, because my scorers return between 20000 and 100000 scores. Although I admit that patching the code is not the ideal solution, and I shouldn't endorse that idea to the grand public, the condition is there in order to catch errors that may have happened elsewhere. If you know that your scorer is not returning multiple values by error, then you can safely remove that condition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and yes that is quite scary :D I think I'll stick with my solution (or something similar) hoping that future version will implement this.

Comment: Thank you. I will still keep the answer up, in case others may find this useful. As indicated, it is an ongoing issue in scikit learn, and you are not the only one encountering this problem. I edited my answer to make it clear that the code you have written is perfect to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Has this question  been addressed by version .17+, if so could you please update your answer...thanks...

Comment: As @eickenberg says, you can just comment the `isinstance` check and then pass any scoring function built-in scikit-learn (such as `sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support`). Be sure to make a scorer using the `sklearn.metrics.make_scorer` function.

Answer (score 4):

You could use this:

```
from sklearn import metrics
from multiscorer import MultiScorer
import numpy as np

scorer = MultiScorer({
    'F-measure' : (f1_score, {...}),
    'Precision' : (precision_score, {...}),
    'Recall' : (recall_score, {...})
})

...

cross_val_score(clf, X, target, scoring=scorer)
results = scorer.get_results()

for name in results.keys():
     print '%s: %.4f' % (name, np.average(results[name]) )
```

The source of *multiscorer* is on [Github](https://github.com/StKyr/multiscorer)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code in order to compute Accuracy, Precision, Recall and any other metrics by fitting your estimator only once per cross-validation step.

```
def get_true_and_pred_CV(estimator, X, y, n_folds, cv, params):
    ys = []
    for train_idx, valid_idx in cv:
        clf = estimator(**params)
        if isinstance(X, np.ndarray):
            clf.fit(X[train_idx], y[train_idx])
            cur_pred = clf.predict(X[valid_idx])
        elif isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            clf.fit(X.iloc[train_idx, :], y[train_idx]) 
            cur_pred = clf.predict(X.iloc[valid_idx, :])
        else:
            raise Exception('Only numpy array and pandas DataFrame ' \
                            'as types of X are supported')

        ys.append((y[valid_idx], cur_pred))
    return ys


def fit_and_score_CV(estimator, X, y, n_folds=10, stratify=True, **params):
    if not stratify:
        cv_arg = sklearn.cross_validation.KFold(y.size, n_folds)
    else:
        cv_arg = sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds)

    ys = get_true_and_pred_CV(estimator, X, y, n_folds, cv_arg, params)    
    cv_acc = map(lambda tp: sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(tp[0], tp[1]), ys)
    cv_pr_weighted = map(lambda tp: sklearn.metrics.precision_score(tp[0], tp[1], average='weighted'), ys)
    cv_rec_weighted = map(lambda tp: sklearn.metrics.recall_score(tp[0], tp[1], average='weighted'), ys)
    cv_f1_weighted = map(lambda tp: sklearn.metrics.f1_score(tp[0], tp[1], average='weighted'), ys)

    # the approach below makes estimator fit multiple times
    #cv_acc = sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score(algo, X, y, cv=cv_arg, scoring='accuracy')
    #cv_pr_weighted = sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score(algo, X, y, cv=cv_arg, scoring='precision_weighted')
    #cv_rec_weighted = sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score(algo, X, y, cv=cv_arg, scoring='recall_weighted')   
    #cv_f1_weighted = sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score(algo, X, y, cv=cv_arg, scoring='f1_weighted')
    return {'CV accuracy': np.mean(cv_acc), 'CV precision_weighted': np.mean(cv_pr_weighted),
            'CV recall_weighted': np.mean(cv_rec_weighted), 'CV F1_weighted': np.mean(cv_f1_weighted)}
```

I frequently use these functions instead of cross_val_score to compute multiple statistics altogether. You can change quality metrics by the desired.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful if you looking **multiple-metrics** with **multi-classes**. With the latest [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#using-multiple-metric-evaluation) in scikit learn 0.19 and above; you can pass your own dictionary with metric functions;

```
custom_scorer = {'accuracy': make_scorer(accuracy_score),
                 'balanced_accuracy': make_scorer(balanced_accuracy_score),
                 'precision': make_scorer(precision_score, average='macro'),
                 'recall': make_scorer(recall_score, average='macro'),
                 'f1': make_scorer(f1_score, average='macro'),
                 }
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train,
        cv = 10, scoring = custom_scorer)
```